# How to handle Save File dialog box in firefox using selenium with python?

Tags: python-2.6

I'm trying to download .csv file using selenium tool in python but after clicked on save file link in web page, the browser is showing me dialog box.I tried "alert" to handle this but it gives me error like, alert is not present....
I'm using python as a scripting language and selenium as a tool.
 here is the my code:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:\Temp\')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.window_handles
driver.swich_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
url=''
driver.get(url)
pass=driver.find_element_by_id('pswd')
pass.send_keys('xyz123')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('FileName').click()
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

Comment: What is the exact MIME type of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I am done with Save file dialog box. I have handled it with some firefox profile preference settings. Since I was not unable to find out the exact MIME type I used all possible.
Below is my code to handle the Save file Dialog box :

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) 
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', r'C:\Temp\')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.useWindow', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone', False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
url=''
driver.get(url)
pass=driver.find_element_by_id('pswd')
pass.send_keys('xyz123')
driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('FileName').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Typo error. Should be `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])`. Missing **t** in switch. One more thing, path should be absolute rather than relative to i.e. script location. While using Windows you should use "r" prefix `r'C:\Temp\'` or use double backslashes `'C:\\Temp\\'`. Trailing backslash is not required.

Comment: Thanks so much @WojciechJakubas . I fixed the typo and also used  absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 import time
 import pyautogui

try :



driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.citysdk.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/DELIVERABLE_WP4_TA_SRS_0.21.pdf")
# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
# Click the OK button and close

time.sleep(5)
webelem = driver.find_element_by_id('download')
webelem.click()

time.sleep(5)
print('press enter')
pyautogui.press('enter')


except Exception as err:
 print('ERROR: %sn' % str(err))

 driver.quit()
```